# Python continue in csv reader loop skips all rows

Tags: python, django, loops, csv, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a CSV file and I have a `try..except` block to catch malformed data. The fist line on the file I am testing with has a bad entry which it should skip, but then it also skips every subsequent line. If I delete the first row with the bad entry the rest of the data loads as expected.

```
csvfile = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['doc'].file, encoding=request.encoding)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

next(reader) ## Skip the header line

for r in reader:
    data = {'field1' : r[1], 'field2' : r[2]}

    try:
        my_object = MyObject.objects.create(**data)
    except:
        ## There was en error with the data
        continue
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why every line gets skipped if only the first line actually contains malformed data. The other lines work if the first line is removed..

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `dialect` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)?

Comment: is there more to the loop that you don't just call `pass` in the except block?

Comment: @Aaron no there isn't and I had tried removing the `continue` but the result is the same.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis setting the `dialect` has also had no effect.

Comment: @apardes what exception does `MyObject.objects.create()` throw when `**data` is mal-formed? you are catching everything, and possibly hiding the issue by ignoring absolutely all errors

Comment: I'm wondering if when `MyObject` throws the exception, some internal state is modified that makes it continue throwing exceptions in subsequent calls even when good data is passed